# Cosmosdb Resource Token Authorization Header using a REST call

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Cosmosdb has the concept of a `permission` for a `user`.  That permission contains a `token` that can be used to access a specified partition for a limited time with limited access.

I've created a resource token broker, which creates the permission, retrieves the token and returns it to a client Xamarin Forms app. So far so good.

If I am using the `DocumentClient` from the `.NET` SDK, that token - unmodified - works great.

However, I'd like to avoid having a dependency on `DocumentClient` in my app and just instead make REST api calls directly to Cosmosdb.

If I put that `token` in the authorization header, I get format errors for that header.  I can't find the source code to the SDK, and all the samples are built modifying a master token.

Can anyone explain/point/sample me on what I have to do to that `resource token` that I get from the `permission` to make it an acceptable header so I can just make a REST call?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I think you already know how to get resource token. All your jobs are good except the resource token format. You need to [urlencode](https://www.urlencoder.org/) your resource token then your code will be fine. I tested it successfully.

```
var databaseId = "db";
var collectionId = "coll";
var datetime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");
var version = "2017-02-22";
var resourceId = $"dbs/{databaseId}/colls/{collectionId}";
var auth = "type%3Dresource%26ver%3D1%26sig%3Dny%2BUlL6QIWR69OfiaSjTsw%3D%3D%3B%2Ba%2FwmK37zLn%2FoilfztnXpfyCN3n9tChunmpBdROF8BH4**********************oU0BJ4z8aDZT%2F%2FgTVJ0hgpXTK8UYMOrL5di3he9wbvQwFkFOdpXD7%2B%2Byhmb1uUOnq%2Fyp454O2fQKR8uA3KaiLCCjYZ6qr%2BQ%2BTV1Cu1u%2F6Yj34nc4UYtpRBX5K************qCGjhvpQ%3D%3D%3B";

var urlPath = $"https://***.documents.azure.com/dbs/db/colls/coll/docs/1";
Uri uri = new Uri(urlPath);
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", datetime);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", version);   
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", auth);
HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
var status = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
var message = response.RequestMessage;
```

Comment: I marked this as the answer as no one was really willing to take a shot at this, so that you, Jay, for that one.  I'm going to try to add some more facts to the answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

Jay's solution was correct.  I was missing a couple of parts.  This entry is for any poor devil facing the same things.

1. The token that actually comes back from Cosmosdb in the permission object is not encoded, as Jay pointed out.  As of .Net Core 2.x you need to use `WebUtility.UrlEncode(token)` to get it in the right format. I spent an hour using `HtmlEncode` not `UrlEncode`.  I'm an idiot.

{**UPDATE:** I'm even dumber than originally thought.  You have to use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`, not `WebUtility.UrlEncode`.  This is because they encode differently.  `WebUtility` ends up with stuff like `%3D` while `HttpUtility` encodes it `%3d`.  That's not important *except when it comes to auth tokens.*  When I ran Fiddler on a DocumentClient call I noticed the tokens contains lower cased encoding values.}  **So ignore #1 above and use `HttpUtility` instead.**

2. I mentioned that I was using partitions in the original question, but Jay's answer didn't cover that, so I was still failing.  I was specifying a partition key, but it's not clear from the docs whether that's the `partition key` **path** or the `partition key` **value**.  And that's not obvious if you believe that the permission token will contain a permission key **value** when it's created.  No way to know what's going on under the covers.  Trial and error. My personal fav.
3. But the less than obvious kicker is the format of the partition key.  If you are limiting the permission to a partition then you need to specify the partition in the header, like this:

   `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey", partitions);`
4. And you need to format the `partitions` variable like this:

   ```
   string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new[] { "b39bcd43-8d3d-*********-4e4492fa3e7d" });
   ```

And that's because Cosmodb is expecting an `array` of partition keys, even though it only accepts on partition key in the list (as I understand it anyway). If you don't want to use `JsonConvert` you can build it manually, using `$"[\"{yourPartitionKey}\"]"`.

After all that it worked like a peach.  Thanks, again, Jay!

Comment: It seems my answer is very imperfect. Really appreciate for your sharing!

Comment: No, man, it was great.  I was really struggling that it was even possible and the error codes were not helpful at all.  You proving to me it could be done was what broke the ice.